# Boot from (hd0,0) ext4 daecfb55-8eef-4a7a-b958-f9c3db33e2ff starting up

Tags: virtual-machine, ubuntu-14.04

Virtual Machine Manager, when I start the Ubuntu VM got the boot error as

'Boot from (hd0,0) ext4 daecfb55-8eef-4a7a-b958-f9c3db33e2ff starting up..'

as per in the screenshot [boot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg7Kd.png)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like an error. It's just a message from your bootloader telling you where it's booting from. Ensure your machine has enough resources to boot. Underpowered virtual machines boot very slowly.